# C practice task (recursion)

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, sum

I've been struggling with the following problem for a whole day now. I have problems at start. I can't figure out how to use recursion for this particular problem. I will really appreciate the help since my final exam is in few days. Cheers

Let there be an integer array "a" with "n" elements. Write recursive function `sumExists` which will for given number `m` return **1** if it's possible to write `m` as sum of elements of array `a`, or **0** if it isn't. Elements from array "a" can be used only once. Prototype for function `sumExists` is:  `int sumExists( int a[] , int n, int m );`

Example:

```
a[5] = { 15, 9, 4, 2, 1 } , n=5, m=17. Function sumExists returns 1;

a[5] = { 15, 9, 4, 2, 1 } , n=5, m=8. Function sumExists returns 0;
```

Code:

```
int sumExists(int a[],int n, int m) {
    int i;
    if(m == 0) return 1;
    for(i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        m = m - a[i];
        if(sumExists(a,i,m)) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure of being a C question, looks like an algorithmic one... Try a backtracking. A good starting point : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: Edited with code I wrote that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
int sumExists(int a[], int n, int m) {
    if (n == 0)
        return m == 0;
    return sumExists(a, n - 1, m - a[n - 1]) || sumExists(a, n - 1, m);
}
```

The recursion checks:

whether there is such a sum **with** the `n-1` element (since calling with size `n-1` and subtracting `a[n-1]` from `m`. as if to include `a[n-1]` in the sum `m`).

### or

if there's such a sum **without** the `n-1` element (skipping `a[n-1]` and checking with `a[1..n-1]`).

Comment: Works like charm! Would you be kind enough to explain the logic behind your solution? :)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is usually very helpful to OP and others to have a brief explanation of the code.

Comment: +1 This solution is quite elegant. @user2301925 The recursion checks whether there is such a sum *With* the `n-1` element `or` if there's such a sum *Without* the `n-1` element. http://xkcd.com/1270/

Comment: @ArnonZilca thanks.
If the array is empty we can stop recursing, since the sum is 0.

Comment: Thanks guys, you rock! I'm not an expert but I think my university professors gave far less elegant solution (there was like 10 code lines) so you should be proud of yourself if that means anything to you :D.